# How do I produce a Hanning smoothing over data points within a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, smoothing

I have a dictionary, with 100 key, each key having 500 values.

```
{'apple': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1....],'pears: [0.6, 0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1....]....'oranges: [0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1.....]}
```

I want to smooth over the values, specifically using the hanning methodology, so that it produces smooth lines when plotted in pandas? Any guidance on how can I do this would be appreciate.

Comment: You may need to look at `np.hanning()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hanning.html

Comment: @Wen Oh there's a hamming and hanning too! :D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes... before searching I only know hamming ..learn something new from Op

Comment: I also found this: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/SignalSmooth. However, Im not sure how to get from my dictionary to the array as described :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic intuition here is to use `df.rolling` and specify a custom `win_type`.

```
df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1, win_type='hanning').sum()

   apple  oranges  pears
0    0.0      0.0    0.0
1    0.0      0.2    0.6
2    0.0      0.1    0.2
3    0.0      0.0    0.0
4    0.2      0.1    0.2
```

---

<sub>I didn't know there was a "Hanning" window... but there is! Pretty neat...</sub>

Comment: it is neat ~ :)

Comment: I think for .rolling you need to use v0.18.0rc1.

Comment: @AlexTrevylan We're currently in v0.21. Please upgrade with `pip install --upgrade pandas`.